# Error when passing argument to a command in a bash script

Tags: bash

I would like to execute a command like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
`which rvmsudo` `which program` argument
```

but I get this issue

```
/usr/bin/env: argument: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You want to pass the argument you give to the script as the argument to the command inside the script?  Then you should change the argument to $1

Comment: unrelated to your error but you must use `#!/bin/bash` if you really want bash, otherwise your script will run in compatibility mode (POSIX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure, all of the which statements return valid:

```
#!/bin/bash

RVMSUDO=`which rvmsudo`
test -z "$RCMSUDO" && exit 1

PROGRAM=`which program`
test -z "$PROGRAM" && exit 2

$RVMSUDO $PROGRAM argument
```